# Как добавить кастомный текст в последнюю строку textView

Tags: android, android-sdk, textview, android-textview

Как реализовать textView с кастомным текстом в последней строке?

Пример реализации:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При условии, что превышено заданное количество строк текста, должна появляться надпись "Показать полностью...". Как это можно реализовать? Всё, что удалось найти относится к expandable textView, т.е. текст разворачивается при клике.

Comment: тут, похоже, не один, а 2 TextView. И если кол-во символов в первом превышает определенное число, то показывается второй

Comment: @metalurgus Да, именно так и я реализовал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно по разному.

1. Самый простой способ - установить нужное предельное кол-во символов в строке, заменять остаток текста на многоточие и добавить перенос строки и нужный текст с нужным оформлением через `Span` или `Html.fromHtml("<p><font color='#0000FF'>Синий текст</font></p>`
2. Установить для `TextView` аттрибут `maxLines` на заданное число и добавив `ellipsize="end"`. Далее надо вычислить превышен ли предел кол-ва строк. Это не тривиальная задача. Можете воспользоваться примерами [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22217849/3212712) (Придётся переопределять `TextView`), после чего асинхронно получать кол-во строк в `TextView` и добавлять ещё одно ниже с синим текстом.